# how to append a circle with a label to indicate information to rectangle node and remove the circle before download

Tags: javascript, d3.js, append, clone, clonenode

I have a vertical D3JS tree where the nodes are rectangles.  I would like to append a circle with the italic letter "*i*" to the top right corner of the rectangle node to indicate that the node has additional information.  I managed to append the italic letter "i" only, however, I am not able to put it in a circle and still keep the node clickable. Also I use cloning for downloading the tree as a SVG file and would like to remove this appended circle and the letter "*i*" from the cloned group element before downloading and printing.

```js
var treeData = [{
  "name": "Top Level",
  "parent": "null",
  "remark": "yes",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Level 2: A",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "remark": "yes",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Son of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A",
          "remark": "null"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A",
          "remark": "null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Level 2: B",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "remark": "null"
    }
  ]
}];

//*************************************************************************************
// 1. Create the button
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "download file";
//*************************************************************************************

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  rectW = 100,
  rectH = 30,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

//swap x and y for vertical
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
    //  .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });
  });

//var gElement = document.createElement('svg:g');
var gElement = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, 'g');
gElement.setAttribute("id", "fg");
console.log(gElement);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append(function() {
    return gElement;
  }) //The argument to .append() has to be a function, you can't just pass element to it.
  //    .append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");


function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  //swap x and y for vertical
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    //nodeEnter.append("circle")
    //  .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);


  // IAH 20/01/2019 Filter to put tooltip only on nodes that have information associated with it
  nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
      return (d.remark != 'null')
    })
    .append("text")
    .attr("id", "infoText")
    .attr("x", 96)
    .attr("y", 7)
    .attr("dy", ".30em")
    .style("font-style", "italic")
    .style("font-family", "serif")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .text("i");

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  //swap x and y for vertical layout
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  //nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .style("stroke", "black")
    //  .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  //vertical switch x and y positions
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  //nodeExit.select("circle")
  nodeExit.select("rect")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

//*************************************************************************************
// 2. Append button somewhere
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button)
  .setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")");

//*************************************************************************************

function svgDataURL(svg) {
  var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
  var dataURL = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
  return dataURL;
}

button.onclick = function() {
  var svgElement = document.querySelector('svg');
  var svgWH = svgElement.getBBox();

  var canvasWidth = svgWH.width;
  var canvasHeight = svgWH.height;

  var groupElement = document.getElementById('fg');
  groupElement.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0,0)");

  const bb = groupElement.getBBox();

  // clone the svg to avoid destroying it while appending to the svg namespace
  let clonedGroupElement = groupElement.cloneNode(true);

  var svgContent = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');

  svgContent.setAttribute('viewBox', ' ' + bb.x + ' ' + bb.y + '  ' + bb.width + ' ' + bb.height);

  svgContent.setAttribute("width", "100%");
  svgContent.setAttribute("height", "100%");
  svgContent.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

  // try to remove the information icon before downloading
  var rmText = document.getElementById('infoText');
  console.log(rmText);

  svgContent.appendChild(clonedGroupElement); // use the cloned nodes

  var dl = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(dl);
  dl.setAttribute("href", svgDataURL(svgContent)); // function svgDataURL expects a node
  dl.setAttribute("download", "test.svg");
  dl.click();
  dl.remove();

  svgContent.removeChild(clonedGroupElement);
};
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  /*
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please turn the code into a runnable [mre]. That will make it easier to answer and will increase the likelihood of getting good answers.

Comment: @RubenHelsloot please see this fiddle I created. https://jsfiddle.net/hawashim/ovLaseqc/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a dummy attribute `ignore-export` and was able to use `querySelectorAll()` to select all elements with that attribute and remove them. Note that the [`node.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove) function is not supported in IE, but there is a polyfill available at MDN.

I didn't have any problems with the nodes not responding when I drew the circle, but if you experience it, let me know.

```js
var treeData = [{
  "name": "Top Level",
  "parent": "null",
  "remark": "yes",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Level 2: A",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "remark": "yes",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Son of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A",
          "remark": "null"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A",
          "remark": "null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Level 2: B",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "remark": "null"
    }
  ]
}];

//*************************************************************************************
// 1. Create the button
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "download file";
//*************************************************************************************

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  rectW = 100,
  rectH = 30,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

//swap x and y for vertical
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
    //  .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });
  });

//var gElement = document.createElement('svg:g');
var gElement = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, 'g');
gElement.setAttribute("id", "fg");
console.log(gElement);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append(function() {
    return gElement;
  }) //The argument to .append() has to be a function, you can't just pass element to it.
  //    .append("svg:g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");


function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  //swap x and y for vertical
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    //nodeEnter.append("circle")
    //  .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);


  // IAH 20/01/2019 Filter to put tooltip only on nodes that have information associated with it
  var nodesWithInfo = nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
    return (d.remark != 'null')
  });
  
  nodesWithInfo
    .append("circle")
    .attr("export-ignore", true)
    .attr("cx", 96)
    .attr("cy", 7)
    .attr("r", 10);
  
  nodesWithInfo
    .append("text")
    .attr("export-ignore", true)
    .attr("id", "infoText")
    .attr("x", 96)
    .attr("y", 7)
    .attr("dy", ".30em")
    .style("font-style", "italic")
    .style("font-family", "serif")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .text("i");

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  //swap x and y for vertical layout
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  //nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .style("stroke", "black")
    //  .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  //vertical switch x and y positions
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  //nodeExit.select("circle")
  nodeExit.select("rect")
    .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

//*************************************************************************************
// 2. Append button somewhere
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button)
  .setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")");

//*************************************************************************************

function svgDataURL(svg) {
  var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
  var dataURL = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
  return dataURL;
}

button.onclick = function() {
  var svgElement = document.querySelector('svg');
  var svgWH = svgElement.getBBox();

  var canvasWidth = svgWH.width;
  var canvasHeight = svgWH.height;

  var groupElement = document.getElementById('fg');
  groupElement.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0,0)");

  const bb = groupElement.getBBox();

  // clone the svg to avoid destroying it while appending to the svg namespace
  let clonedGroupElement = groupElement.cloneNode(true);

  var svgContent = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');

  svgContent.setAttribute('viewBox', ' ' + bb.x + ' ' + bb.y + '  ' + bb.width + ' ' + bb.height);

  svgContent.setAttribute("width", "100%");
  svgContent.setAttribute("height", "100%");
  svgContent.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

  // try to remove the information icon before downloading
  clonedGroupElement.querySelectorAll('[export-ignore]').forEach(function(node) {
    node.remove();
  });

  svgContent.appendChild(clonedGroupElement); // use the cloned nodes

  var dl = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(dl);
  dl.setAttribute("href", svgDataURL(svgContent)); // function svgDataURL expects a node
  dl.setAttribute("download", "test.svg");
  dl.click();
  dl.remove();

  svgContent.removeChild(clonedGroupElement);
};
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.link {
  /*
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```